# Extract Digits From String After Capturing It From File

Tags: string, bash, variables, for-loop, sed

I'm trying to retrieve a memory value from file, and compare it to reference value. But one thing at a time....
I've attempted using set/source/grep/substring to variable but non of them actually worked. Then I found a way to do it using a for loop (see code). 
The issue: I'm receiving the entire string from the file, but I can't manage to get rid of the last character in it.

```
 #!/bin/bash

 #source start_params.properties
 #mem_val= "$default.default.minmaxmemory.main"
 #mem_val= grep "default.default.minmaxmemory.main" start_params.properties
 for mLine in $(grep 'default.default.minmaxmemory.main' start_params.properties)
  do
    echo "$mLine"
 done
 echo "${mLine:4:5}"  # didn't get rid of the last `m` in `-max4095m`
 v1="max"
 v2="m"
 echo "$mLine" | sed -e "s/.*${v1}//;s/${v2}.*//" #this echo the right value.
```

The loop iterates twice:
First output:  `default.default.minmaxmemory.main=-min512m`
Second output: `-max4096m`
Then the sed command output is `4096`,but how can I change the last line in the code S.T. it'll store the value in a variable?

Thank you for your suggestions,

Comment: Use command substitution: `v=$(echo "$mLine" | sed -e "s/.*${v1}//;s/${v2}.*//")`. Alternative: if all you need is to get rid of non-digit characters, use: `v=$(tr -dC '[:digit:]' <<<"$mLine")`.

Comment: @mklement Great! Thank you very much, I used the latter.

Comment: You're welcome. Here's a bash cheat sheet that may come in handy: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashSheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `grep` to filter the `max` part and then another a `grep -o` to extract the numbers:

```
echo "$mLine" | grep "$max" | grep -o '[[:digit:]]*'
```

Comment: Slightly shorter version of the `grep` command: `egrep -o '\d+'`

Comment: Hi h3nr1x, thank you for your suggestion, but when I try `echo "$mLine" | grep "-max" |grep -o '[[:digit:]]*'` `grep` doesn't like the `-` sign infront of max.

Comment: and when I remove the `-` from infront of `max` the output is identical to my initial one `max4096m`

Comment: @Simply_Me: Use `grep -- "-max"`. The `--` tells grep than anything that follows is NOT an option.

Comment: @mklement thanks for the corrections and suggestions, this answer  should go in your rep, I'll upvote a couple of your answers to compensate ;)

Answer (score 0):

```sh
$ sed '/max[0-9]/!d; s/.*max//; s/m//' start_params.properties
4096
```

- remove lines not matching `max[0-9]`
- remove first part of line until `max`
- remove final `m`

Comment: Hi @Steven, I'm sorry but this isn't working, as max isn't a unique name in the file. That is the reason I'm looking for the property first.